# Sound generator on FPGA with VHDL code

Tags: vhdl, fpga, speaker

I need to use keyboard as input for musical notes, and digilent speaker as output.
I plan to use only one octave. 
My most intriguing questions are:

1. How do I represent the musical notes in VHDL code.
2. How do I (or do I need to) implement a DAC module that uses Spartan 3E Starter's built-in DAC? I have read on other forums that it can't be implemented. I need to use it in order to transmit the note to the speaker. The teacher who supervises my and my colleagues' projects suggested me to look into PWM for that(but all I've found is explained in electronic manner, no accompanying code, or explanation on implementation).
3. Besides keyboard controller, a processing module(for returning the note corresponding to the pressed key from the notes vector) and DAC, that I have figured out so far that I need, what else do I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There is a DAC (see comments)

There is no DAC on the Spartan-3E Starter Kit. Using a low-pass PWM signal is a common way to generate analog signal level from digital output.

You need to define a precision for your PWM, let's say 8 bits or 256 levels. For each audio sample you want to output, you need to count from 0 to 255. When the counter is less than the desired sample level, output 1, otherwise output 0. When the counter reach 255, reset it and go to the next sample.

Thus, if you want 8 bits precision (256 levels) and 8KHz signal, the counter will have to run at 256*8000 = 2.048MHz.

For your other questions, there is no easy answer. It's your job, as designer, to figure that out.

Comment: how about this (slide 3) http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards/s3estarter/files/s3esk_picoblaze_dac_control.pdf

Comment: You're totally right, I remember now! We had a project using an external DAC, so I thought it didn't have one. The problem with the DAC onboard is that you can't use it at the same time as the ADC. You have to time multiplexed the two, which was not possible for us. Sorry for the misinformation.